# Node.js- Comapring items from AWS DynamoDB- only lowercases

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to get Items from my AWS DynamoDB, via Lambda, which satisfy condition:

```
if (typeof event.keyWord != "undefined") { 

                var str = event.keyWord;
                str = str.toLowerCase();
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":keyWord"] = {"S": str};

                params.FilterExpression = "contains (#nm, :keyWord)";
                }
```

I send string (keyWord) from my android app, then call toLowerCase function on it and compare it with #nm from DB. My question is, how can I call similar function (toLowerCase) on #nm before comparing them? My whole code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


    var params = {
        TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
       // ProjectionExpression: "locationLat, locationLon",
        ProjectionExpression: "ID, description, endDate, imagePath, locationLat, locationLon, #nm, #tp" //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#nm": "name",
            "#tp": "type",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
             ":lower_lon": {"N": event.low_lon},
             ":higher_lon": {"N": event.high_lon}, 
             ":lower_lat": {"N": event.low_lat},
             ":higher_lat": {"N": event.high_lat}
        }
    };


     if (typeof event.keyWord != "undefined") { 

                var str = event.keyWord;
                str = str.toLowerCase();
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":keyWord"] = {"S": str};

                params.FilterExpression = params.FilterExpression + " and contains (#nm, :keyWord)";
                }

  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {

        data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
            console.log(
                record.name.S + "");
        });


        context.succeed(data.Items); // data.Items


      }
  });
};
```

Comment: not sure this can be done - if you could make sure your keywords are stored lower case (when you add records) it could work, the other way would be to plug elastic search (or cloud search) into dynamodb and make search query there

Comment: Can you send me any resources to those plugins, please?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.DynamoDBLogstash.html

Comment: I follow this instruction: https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-input-dynamodb. I stuck on this "Install the Bundler gem by typing the following:

jruby -S gem install bundler" Where should type it? To which comand prompt

Comment: Those aren't really "plugins", they are separate services that could possibly be hooked up to DynamoDB in some way. The actual answer to your question is: either store all the values in DynamoDB in lowercase, or use a completely different service that supports case insensitive searches/queries, like ElasticSearch.